# 'rasa shell' giving error after successful execution of 'rasa train'

Tags: rasa-core, rasa

I have trained the rasa model and when I do rasa shell it shows
 2020-04-04 11:57:26 ERROR    rasa.core.actions.action  - Couldn't create message for template 'utter_greet'.
this error. And for actions it is showing 
2020-04-04 11:58:27 ERROR    rasa_sdk.endpoint  - Failed to extract slot job_function with action sales_form
this error. 
Please help me in fixing this error. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Going to need some more details to be able to help with this - what does your domain file look like? Is your action server running? what are the logs before that error?

Answer (score 2):

This issue got fixed when I replaced 'templates' with 'responses' in domain.yml file. I am using rasa 2.0 version. This should work from rasa version 1.7 onwards